# Creating an "edit" page with one or more "line item" sections on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a website that has similarities to an ordering page, and I've decided to write it using ASP.NET Core.

Where I'm currently stuck is I'm creating a page where the user can put in some "order header" information, and then on the page is shown a single "line item" section with a couple things on it (select a product from a drop-down and a 
textbox for quantity). There will also be an "Add line item" button that would add a second, and a third, and so on.

Then there'd be a "Submit" button at the bottom of the page that would save it all - both the order "header" data as well as all of the line items on the page.

Unfortunately, I'm at a loss figuring out how to do this.

My model classes are as follows, but I'm struggling to figure out (or find an example of) how to create the one-or-more structure for the line items:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public class OrderLine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Product CurrentProduct { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty{ get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

Note: this is entirely new development, so if I've gone completely down the wrong path, it's not too late to change course.

Comment: So, what do you actually want help with? Designing the View?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use Javascript to insert additional `<input>` tags into your form when the "Add line item" button is clicked. The trick is to give the correct name to these inputs so that the modelbinder will use them to fill the `OrderLines` collection in your model.

```
@model Order

@{
    // assume available options for Products are generated in controller or ViewModel
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> availableProducts = Model.AvailableProducts ; 
    const string lineItemContainerId = "orderLineItemsContainer";
    const string lineItemTemplateId = "orderLineItem";
    const string addLineItemButtonId = "addOrderLineItem";
}

<div id="@lineItemContainerId">
    @* always show inputs for first order line item; 
       we will also use this as template for additional order lines *@
    <div id="@lineItemTemplateId">
        @* Note that the OrderLines collection must contain an empty OrderLine initially 
           for this Html helper syntax to work - initialize collection in ViewModel ctor *@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrderLines[0].CurrentProduct, availableProducts)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderLines[0].Qty)
        @* Id will be set by Entity Framework when we create the OrderLine entity *@
    </div>
</div>

<button id="@addLineItemButtonId" type="button">Add line item</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var numberOfLineItems = 1;

        // clone and insert template if button is clicked
        $('#@addLineItemButtonId').on('click', function() {
            numberOfLineItems++; 

            // clone template and remove Id attribute from clone
            var newLineInputs = $('#@lineItemTemplateId').clone().removeAttr('id');

            // fix array indices in name attributes of cloned inputs
            // so model binder fills the OrderLines collection correctly
            newLineInputs.children().each(function() {
                 var existingName = $(this).prop('name');
                 // model binder expects zero based indices
                 var fixedName = existingName.replace('[0]', '[' + (numberOfLineItems - 1) + ']');
                 $(this).prop('name', fixedName)
            }); 

            // append cloned inputs to DOM
            $('#@lineItemContainerId').append(newLineInputs);
        });
    });
</script>
```

See also [Model Binding To A List](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).